# Call HTTPS REST service from WCF

Tags: wcf, https

I need to call some REST services from a third parties server over HTTPS. My thinking was that I would create myself a nice little WCF library to handle these calls and deserialise the responses. I'm coming a tad unstuck though.

The services I am trying to call have a test service that simply responds OK.

I have created an OperationContract in my interface as shown below:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    UriTemplate = "test")]
 string Test();
```

In my service code I have a public method below:

```
public string Test()
{
    ChannelFactory<IService1> factory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>("UMS");
    var proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
    var response = proxy.Test();
    ((IDisposable)proxy).Dispose();
    return (string)response;
}
```

My app.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://61.61.34.19/serv/ums/"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              behaviorConfiguration="ums"
              contract="WCFTest.IService1"
              bindingConfiguration="webBinding"
              name="UMS" />
    </client>
    <services>
      <service name="WCFTest.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WCFTest.Service1Behavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/WCFTest/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address ="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFTest.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ums">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate findValue="restapi.ext-ags.801" 
                               storeLocation="CurrentUser" 
                               x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
          </clientCredentials>
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFTest.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>       
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I try to invoke the test method but receive the error "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority '61.61.34.19'."

Can anyone see what I'm missing here?

Any help appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Can you browse to the REST Service from your IE and see the response? Is the client authentication done by the REST Service using a client certificate?

Comment: Yes Rajesh, I can browse from IE and see reponse.

Comment: If your certificate is self signed then have you implemented the ServicePointManager callback method that validates the server certificate. Also are you browsing to the service from the client machine from where your trying to test?

Comment: H Rajesh. The Cert was provided by the 3rd party whose service I need to consume. I am on my dev machine, service is on server elsewhere.

Comment: Have you made sure that the client certificate is being sent across when the request is being made from your machine? Can you do this in the test method --> factory.Credentials.ClientCertificate = "your client cert" and then see if your request succeeds

Answer (score 1):

> Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority '61.61.34.19'.

This typically means there's a problem with the server's SSL cert. Was it self-signed? If so, you have to establish trust for the cert, typically by [trusting the issuing CA or installing the cert in the windows cert store](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Import-or-export-certificates-and-private-keys).

Comment: Cheers Randolph, The cert is installed in the store and if I hit the URI for the test service in IE I can see the result, just struggling to perform the same from WCF. Also tried to call direct from a bog standard WPF app by interrogating cert store, locating the cert and adding to the HttpWebRequest.CientCertificates collection then calling .GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the webHttpBinding security setting from "Transport" to "None".